# in google Apps Script, how to get first column of active range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a script with a .onedit function to select the active range when an edit is made on my sheet.

What I want is, when someone pastes new data into the bottom of the script (usually 5-10 rows by 20 columns), for the script to select the first column of that active range.

As far as I can tell, the .getActiveRange() method only selects the whole range. How can I tweak my code to only return the first column of the active range?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //CORE VARIABLES
  // Setting up columns A & W as the ones to check for edits
  var COLUMNTOCHECK_A = 1;
  var COLUMNTOCHECK_W = 23;
  // Setting where I want the date stamp to appear relative to edited cell (how many cells to the right)
  var DATETIMELOCATION_A = 25;
  var DATETIMELOCATION_W = 4;
  // Sheets you want this function to apply to
  var SHEETNAME = ['Risk Assessments', 'Copy of Risk Assessments']

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on one of the selected sheets
  if(!sheet.getSheetName().includes(SHEETNAME)) {
    var selectedRange = ss.getActiveRange();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedRange.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK_A) {
      var dateTimeCell = selectedRange.offset(0,DATETIMELOCATION_A);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    if( selectedRange.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK_W) {
      var dateTimeCell = selectedRange.offset(0,DATETIMELOCATION_W);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getActiveRange()` returns a range. You can use the [`getRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow()) and [`getNumRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNumRows()) methods on the range class to get the first row index and number of rows of the active range respectively. You would then use [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer)) method on the sheet class to get the first column by row index and number of rows, like so:

```js
const selectedRange = sheet.getActiveRange()
const selectedRangeFirstCol = sheet.getRange(selectedRange.getRow(), 1, selectedRange.getNumRows())
```